# Access Objective-C property dynamically using the name of the property

Tags: objective-c, reflection, key-value-coding, declared-property

I know the string name of a property of an object. How would I go about getting and setting that property using the string?

Answer (score 51, accepted):

While @weichsel is correct, there is a better way.

Use:

```
[anObject valueForKey: @"propertyName"];
```

and

```
[anObject setValue:value forKey:@"propertyName"];
```

Obviously, `@"propertyName"` can be an `NSString` that is dynamically composed at runtime.

This technique is called [Key Value Coding](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/KeyValueCoding/) and is fundamental to Cocoa.

Why this is better is because `-valueForKey` will do what is necessary to "box" whatever type the property returns into an object.  Thus, if the property is of type `int`, it'll return an `NSNumber` instance containing the int.

This is much easier to deal with -- `performSelector` will *only* work for types that *happen* to fit into a pointer's worth of memory.

Note that there is also `-setValue:forKey:`.

Comment: Very handy! Didn't know that.

Answer (score 2):

`@synthesize propertyName` automates the generation of getter and setter methods.

The compiler generates

- `- (id)propertyName;`
- `- (void)setPropertyName;`

If you have a selector as NSString, you can use `performSelector:NSSelectorFromString`.
e.g.:
`[object performSelector:NSSelectorFromString(@"propertyName") ...]`

Comment: You'll have to use `performSelector:withObject:` in order to set the property.