# Accessing property dynamically

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [obj-c access property dynamically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1969897/obj-c-access-property-dynamically)

I'm attempting to access an object’s properties dynamically using strings. I know that we can access classes dynamically etc but is this possible for properties?
For example, instead of directly accessing the property name, can we use a NSString to access it?

```
@property (retain,nonatomic) int height;

NSString *stringName = @"height"; object.stringName = 30.0f;

where object.height == object.stringName;
```

Comment: Look [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1969897/obj-c-access-property-dynamically)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do this using `KVC`.

`[[object valueForKey:@"height"] intValue]`

All properties automatically opt into the KVC system.

Comment: Provided that your object is a child of NSObject.. correct?

Comment: @Muhammad correct, but if your object isn't...you did something weird.

Comment: Thanks heaps. I'll give it a shot. Sorry but what is KVC?

Comment: `Key-value coding is a mechanism for accessing an object’s properties indirectly, using strings to identify properties, rather than through invocation of an accessor method or accessing them directly through instance variables. In essence, key-value coding defines the patterns and method signatures that your application’s accessor methods implement.` From here: http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/KeyValueCoding/Articles/Overview.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20001838-SW1

Comment: Other hard-way solution is to use `performSelector`, but Joshua solutions is better if not the best.  https://github.com/MuhammadHewedy/ObjectMapper/blob/master/ObjectMapper/ObjectMapper/ObjectMapper.m#L165